Why I can't declare a char array as "char* a" format in C language?
As we all know that array name point at the address of array's first element,but why we can't declare a char array as "char* a" format in C language?Why when I declare as this format I can't use scanf("%s",a)?
Thank you for anyone's answer.

char * is a pointer to a char, not a char itself. you can't scan over pointers.

You can but have to add a = malloc( N ); to reserve real memory. Then use scanf("%s", a)".

An array declaration also declares some memory to backup the array elements. A pointer declaration reserves no memory (besides the pointer itself) so the pointer have to be set to a valid address before you can use it.

My question has been solved,thank you!But I can't reply comments now.

a) you can reply comments, you just did b) please create an answer post c) [edit] your question so that enough information is there that others could also have answered it, try for [ask].

Sidenote: Never use %s without limiting the number of characters in the word you want to read.

Does this answer your question? Is an array name a pointer?

char *a; creates a pointer.  But what memory does it point to?  That's important to know when you're using pointers.  char a[BUFSIZE]; is a char array with actual memory.

@TedLyngmo Side note: Never use *scanf ;-)

The answer is "yes you can, if you do it properly."  That's what the following code reveals. Significant is that we allocate memory for the char pointer, and that we confirm allocation success before using the pointer.
Please also note that we limit the character input (99 chars) to scanf() because we only malloc() 100 bytes ( 99 characters plus a terminating NUL ).
Runnable code is here.
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf()  */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc() */

int main()
{
    char *a = malloc(100);
    if(a)
    {
        scanf("%99s",a);
        printf("%s\n",a);
        free(a);
    }
    else
        printf("memory allocation failed!\n");

    return 0;
}

